# Convert Point2f[] to Mat[] OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to convert a Point2f[] to a Mat[] using the OpenCvSharp library and have no idea where to start. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect))
```

This is the code i am trying to translate into OpenCvSharp
[Detect barcodes in python](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/)

This is the first time i have used OpenCvSharp so i can do everything in the linked page except the lines i have include.

Comment: What exactly is your goal?  Point2f is a 2d floating point coordinate and a Mat represents a raster.

Comment: Im trying to translate this code in python to openCvSharp, where c is a Mat

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect))

Comment: Can you toss up a code snippet?  That should help me figure out where to start.  The problem is that Points and Mats are different objects.  One is  a specific place and the other is a grid object.  I have seen Points store odd things, so I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Point>>` overload you were looking for rather than the `Mat` based one.

I was able to get that working by `Select`ing as `Point.Point` and wrapping in a dummy array. Here's the whole code using the example image from your link:

```
// Using NuGet package OpenCvSharp-AnyCPU 2.4.10.20140320. 
var image = Cv2.ImRead("barcode_01.jpg");
var gray = image.CvtColor(OpenCvSharp.ColorConversion.BgraToGray);
var gradX = gray.Sobel(MatType.CV_32F, 1, 0, -1);
var gradY = gray.Sobel(MatType.CV_32F, 0, 1, -1);
var gradient = gray.EmptyClone();
Cv2.Subtract(gradX, gradY, gradient);
Cv2.ConvertScaleAbs(gradient, gradient);         
var kernel = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(StructuringElementShape.Rect, new Size(21, 7));
var closed = (gradient.Blur(new Size(9,9)).Threshold(225, 255, OpenCvSharp.ThresholdType.Binary)).MorphologyEx(OpenCvSharp.MorphologyOperation.Close, kernel);            
Mat[] contours;
var hierarchy = InputOutputArray.Create(new List<Vec4i>());            
closed.Erode(kernel, null, 4).Dilate(kernel, null, 4).FindContours(out contours, hierarchy, OpenCvSharp.ContourRetrieval.External, OpenCvSharp.ContourChain.ApproxSimple);            
var c = contours.ToList().OrderByDescending(mat => mat.ContourArea(false)).FirstOrDefault();
if (c != null)
{
    var rect = Cv2.MinAreaRect(c);
    var box = new[] { rect.Points().Select(p2f => new Point(p2f.X, p2f.Y)) };
    Cv2.DrawContours(image, box, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    image.SaveImage(@"out.png");
}
```